# Is there any way to show mean in box plot using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm just starting using Matplotlib, and I'm trying to learn how to draw a box plot in Python using Colab.

My problem is: **I'm not able to put the median on the graph. The graph just showed the quartiles, mean, and outliers. Can someone help me?**

My code is the following.

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import gspread
import numpy as np
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
sns.set_theme(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

wb = gc.open_by_url('URL_JUST_FOR_EXAMPLE')
boxplot = wb.worksheet('control-Scale10to100')
boxplotData = boxplot.get_all_values()
df = pd.DataFrame(boxplotData[1:], columns=boxplotData[0])
df.drop(df.columns[0], 1, inplace=True)
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
df.dtypes

df.describe()

dfBoxPlotData = df.iloc[:,4:15]
dfBoxPlotData.apply(pd.to_numeric)
dfBoxPlotData.head()
props = dict(whiskers="Black", medians="Black", caps="Black")
ax = df.plot.box(rot=90, fontsize=14, figsize=(15, 8), color=props, patch_artist=True, grid=False, meanline=True, showmeans=True, meanprops=dict(color='red'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried running your code with a sample data set where the mean and median are distinct, and like @tdy showed, as long as the parameters `showmeans=True` and  `meanline=True` are being passed to the `df.plot.box` method, the mean and median should both show up. Is it possible that in your data set, the mean and median are close enough together that they're hard to distinguish?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

mu, sigma = 50., 10. # mean and standard deviation
np.random.seed(42)
s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 30)

df = pd.DataFrame({'values':s})
props = dict(whiskers="Black", medians="Black", caps="Black")
ax = df.plot.box(rot=90, fontsize=14, figsize=(15, 8), color=props, patch_artist=True, grid=False, meanline=True, showmeans=True, meanprops=dict(color='red'))
pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Derek O, thank you, you're right! I checked my dataset and perceived that the mean and median values are close enough to make any distinction on the presented graph.